# Помогите объяснить значение выражения "Хам с четвертью"

Tags: фразеология

Вспомнилось услышанное в детстве выражение "ХАМ С ЧЕТВЕРТЬЮ". Вам такое знакомо? Явно звучит негативная оценка качества характера человека (хам - грубый, наглый человек), усиленная не совсем понятной "четвертью". Как эту "четверть" понимать? Или как "переполненность", чрезмерность свойства (например: тот- полный дурак, а этот - хам с четвертью, т.е. полный, да ещё с четвертью)? Или как совсем не контролирующий себя из-за выпитого человек (здесь четверть в значении меры объёма жидкостей равная 1/4 ведра). Или есть ещё возможные варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Ольга, я обычно не отвечаю на вопросы по неизвестным мне выражениям, если нет достаточно убедительной версии, но тут сделаю исключение. Просто выражение, хоть сугубо местное и не фиксируется нигде, но абсолютно прозрачно. Ваша версия насчет водки ни на чем не основана. Нет в русском языке ни аналогов, ни объяснений, как такой образ мог проникнуть в язык. Нравится - не нравится тут не катит, думаю, и Вас такой подход бы не устроил.

А вот другая, про "полный дурак" скорее всего имеет место. Русским вообще свойственно высшую степень человеческих качеств передавать единицей с дробью. Обычно это, правда "полтора", один с половиной: полтора дурака, полтора Ивана (или "мужика - "об огромном человеке), полтора ума... Хам - не исключение. Михаил Козаков так книгу назвал - "Полтора Хама" (правда, я её не читал целиком, может там и другая какая-то идея заложена). Думаю, "хам с четвертью" из этой же серии, хоть и употреблялось, судя по всему, только Вашим ближайшим окружением.

Comment: Не думаю, что это выражение только моего ближайшего окружения.

Comment: К сожалению, в интернете о нем никто не знает. А почему Вы так считаете? Можете указать на письменную фиксацию?

Comment: А в интернете "тусуются" носители того языка, который "с четвертью"? Моей второй бабусе 103 года и она только телевизором пользуется... Не похожа моя бабка на "словотворца", Употребляла же это выражение очень уверенно, на автомате. К тому же, за письменной фиксацией ездят фольклорные экспедиции в глубинку, мои же родственники "окологородские".  Толстой через нашу малую родину в свою "Ясную Поляну" пешком ходил. Может, у каких-нибудь прозаиков 19-20 вв. есть упоминание, только много ли мы их читали, ОКРОМЯ классиков из школьной программы.

Comment: Ну если судить по тому, что некоторые отвечаю вопросом на вопрос (да еще столь далеко от темы, то да).  Я, позвольте, пропущу пока все ваши рассказы про бабусю (дай ей Бог еще много-много), отвечу на явное Ваше непонимание ситуации. В интернете есть все, а чего нету есть в книгах. Хотя бы потому, что все мало-мальски значимые словари там присутствуют. Словотворцем или фольклористом быть не надо. Если в деревне есть два человека, занющие и употребляющие слово, считайте, что слово фиксировано. Но это не исключает того, что эти два человека из одной деревни ваше ближайшее окружение.

Comment: Смысл же моей сентенции совсем не в том, чтобы как-то принизить роль услышанного Вами. Просто обсуждать что-либо, чего никто, кроме Вас, не слышал, бесполезно. Одни догадки на кофейной гуще, не мой метод... Не хотелось бы на такой уровень переходить.  засим - все. Я свою версию сказал, Ваше дело её услышать или отринуть.

Comment: Ольга, если ваша бабушка употребляет это выражение, почему бы вам у нее не спросить?

Comment: Этой бабуси уже нет в живых.

Comment: Ну я-то понял, что речь о разных бабусях. Остальное - в силе.

Answer (score 0):

Ольга близка к разгадке, ибо бабушка её , уверен, держала в руках произведение М.Э. Козакова https://my-lib.net/read/604292248/#nid2656556:

"И Полтора-Героя тотчас же вышел, с силой прихлопнув дверь. Нюточка заметила, что **он был пьян**. Вначале не поняла, но вскоре назвала его в душе «циником и животным». И окрестила по-своему — Полтора-Хама…"

Comment: Не вижу у Казакова подобной версии. Про книгу, я кстати, давно сказал. Но её вряд ли читала бабушка, которая только телевизор смотрит.

Comment: В 24-м году не могла  бабушка подсесть на телевизор. И ещё лет 30.

Comment: Вы мне? И что с того? Это как-то проясняет Ваше объяснение "через Казакова"?